# How to deal with exception with Deferred await error in Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, coroutine

Our application has many network requests and we are using Coroutines with Retrofit like this:

```
suspend fun fetchAccountInfo() {
    val api = retrofit.create(MainActivityApi::class.java)
    val versionResponse = api.getVersionAsync().await()
    ...
}
```

The problem is that when device is not connected to the internert, Retrofit will throw an exeption and the app will crash. I found [this link](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter/issues/3) that says, put await() into a try/catch like this:

```
suspend fun fetchAccountInfo() {
    val api = retrofit.create(MainActivityApi::class.java)
    try {
        val versionResponse = api.getVersionAsync().await()
    } catch(e: Exception) {
      //
    }
    ...
}
```

But our app has many network requests and this solution is not proper for us. How can I prevent app crashing without putting all await() calls into a try/catch?

Answer (score 1):

Even though wrapping is the preferred method, I believe there is another way(I wouldn't use it personally, but might suit you)

You could create an OkHttp interceptor, which would do the try-catching for every request, and that would return a response created by retrofit's static Response.error(someParams).

You could refer to https://github.com/gildor/kotlin-coroutines-retrofit/issues/34 for the construction, you'd basically have to only change the catch{} block.

Hope this helps, GL!

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by another comment, you can create a custom interceptor that handles exceptions and returns a custom response indicating an error.

```
class TeapotInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()

        val response: Response = try {
            chain.proceed(request)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Log here
            Response.Builder()
                .request(request)
                .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_2)
                .code(418)
                .message("I'm a teapot")
                .build()
        }

        return response
    }
}

val teapotInterceptor = TeapotInterceptor()
OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(teapotInterceptor)
    .build()
```